# How to accommodate mobile browsers with number inputs

Tags: html, forms, input

I'd like to accomodate as many mobile browsers as possible with number `<input>` elements. The only problem is that I'm afraid of using the `type="number"` attribute or `type="tel"` because some browsers may add their own formatting like commas, parenthesis and hyphens.

These fields I'm using can only accept numbers. I am presently using `pattern="[0-9]*"` which works brilliantly on an iPhone.

However, on an iPad or any Android phone/table the patter attribute will not automatically select the numeric keypad.

What would be the best approach for bringing up the numeric keypad on as many mobile browsers as possible. Commas, parenthesis and hyphens will break the form.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why not filter out non-numeric upon submission of the form?

Comment: @ChrisForrence That could be an answer